# How to append the output of Parallel Grep to a file?

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, grep, bigdata

I have a file of 500 MB, and a pattern file of 20MB. Since it was taking too much time to grep the 1.2 million patterns from the file with 5 million lines, I split the pattern file into 100 parts.
I tried to run Grep parallely with the multiple patterns as below.

```
for pat1 in vailtar_*
do
    parallel --block 75M --pipe grep $pat1 infile >> outfile
done;
```

But I cannot get the output to append to a file. I tried without the block option and as below too -

```
cat infile | parallel --block 75M --pipe grep $pat1 >> outfile
< infile parallel --block 75M --pipe grep $pat1 >> outfile
```

Is there anyway to make the parallel grep append the output to a file?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it will work better like this?

```
for pat1 in vailtar_*
do
    parallel --block 75M --pipe grep -f $pat1 < infile
done > outfile
```

That will take all the output from everything inside the `for` loop, and put it in `outfile`.

Incidentally, I think you meant to use `infile` as stdin, instead of as an argument to grep, and I think you meant to have `-f $pat`, not just the filename as the pattern. I've fixed both issues in my version.

---

However, if I were trying to solve this problem I might do it like this:

```
parallel 'grep -f {} infile' ::: vailtar_*
```

(I've not tested that.)

Comment: Sorry, I was trying -f option itself in the parallel grep. I'm trying your way, the 2nd one. I need some time to check the result though :)

Comment: I have to add that
" parallel 'grep -f {} infile' ::: vailtar_* "
works much better, it is about 10X faster than using a for-loop

Comment: This example deals with the problem of grepping n lines for m regular expressions http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Grepping-n-lines-for-m-regular-expressions